# laravel 4.2 and join function

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

```
$options = table::join('table1', function($join) {
$join->on('table1.table_id','=','table.id');
$join->take(1);
})->get();
```

Is there a way to do this, i get error on take function.

the table and table1 has one to many relation, and i'd like to have on join just the first record of table1.

Thanks
Vincenzo

Comment: Not sure on this, but shouldn't the take be outside of the join?

Comment: I think take() can be applied to Collection only, that's why the function should be out and before get().